# Find all $z \in \Bbb{C}$ such that $z^3 = \overline{(-5z^2)}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all $z \in \Bbb{C}$ such that $z^3 = \overline{(-5z^2)}$

How to solve this?

I have to apply de formula of Moivre?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
Write $z$ in a polar form: $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ and calculate firstly  $\rho$ using the fact that $|e^{i\varphi}|=1\;\;\forall{\varphi}\in\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 3):

If you first consider the norms / modulus of these numbers you'll easily determine what $|z|$ must be, then you just have to find an appropriate angle $\alpha$ such that $3 \alpha = -2 \alpha$ (from de Moivre formula like you've said)

Comment: Actually, $3\alpha=-2\alpha+\pi+2n\pi$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 0):

let $z=a+bi$

$(a+bi)^3 = \overline{-5(a+bi)^2}$

$a^3+3a^2bi-3ab^2-b^3i = \overline{-5(a^2+2abi-b^2)}$

$a^3-3ab^2+i(3a^2b-b^3) = \overline{-5(a^2-b^2)-10abi}$

$a^3-3ab^2+i(3a^2b-b^3) = -5(a^2-b^2)+10abi$

$\therefore a^3-3ab^2=-5(a^2-b^2)$ and $3a^2b-b^3=10ab$

Solving them, we get 6 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> Find all $z \in \Bbb C \text{ }|\text{  } z^3 = \overline{(-5z^2)}$

I would start by saying that $\overline{(-5z^2)}=-5(\overline{z})^2$

Since you're suppose to apply De Moivre's theorem, I would begin by saying that if we write $z$ as 
$$z=r\,\text{cis}(x)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=r\,e^{ix}$$
this is the same as finding all $r$ and $x$ such that $r^3\text{cis}(3x)=-5r^2\overline{\text{cis}(2x)}=-5r^2\text{cis}(-2x)$

So, excluding the case that $r=0$ (giving us the solution $z=0$), we have
$$
r \frac{\text{cis}(3x)}{\text{cis}(-2x)}=-5
$$
Or, by De Moivre's theorem,
$$
r\text{cis}(5x)=-5
$$
That is, $r = 5$ and
$$
\cos(5x)+i\sin(5x)=(-1)+i(0)
$$
You should be able to find the corresponding values of $x$.  In doing so, you will have all 6 solutions to the original equation.

Comment: Why 6 solutions?

Comment: @Did: For every solution to $\sin(5x)=0$, $5\text{cis}(x)$ is a solution to the original problem.  That gives us five solutions.  On top of that, we have $z=0$, giving us 6.

Comment: Right, I forgot the solution z=0...